# Why is my Unity rocket flame particle effect jittery?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am making a flame particle effect for my rocket engine, but when I set the simulation space to world the effect "lagged" behind the rocket as intended; however, it sort of jitters and doesn't leave a smooth consistent path like before.

I tried slowing down the simulation speed or particle speed and shortening the lifetime, this fixed it, but I need something else because this doesn't make the flame come out fast enough. Is there any way of getting around this?

I also tried setting inherit velocity to 1, but that somehow made the effect worse.

Comment: We cant see what you see. You need to provide minimal viable code and instructions for us to recreate it

Comment: Sorry, I had a picture, but it didn't upload for some reason

Answer (score -1):

Someone in unity answers helped me figure out, I just needed to enable interpolation on the rigidbody, here's the picture I forgot to include, and what it looks like after fixing it.[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU5To.png) [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMG7X.png)